# Qt MySQL driver not support transaction

Tags: mysql, qt

I am working on Qt Ubuntu 16.04 and install all required qt using apt-get install.
And install mysql driver by :

`apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql`

But the problem is that the driver does not support transaction. I check using this code :

```
auto database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "TEST");
qDebug() << database.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions);
//it printed false
```

How to make the driver has feature transaction?

Comment: hi check if you did all the requiremnt, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check after the connection open, the feature is available.